# Update a document with many fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have got this document in mongo db

```
 { _id: 5e1f159e03ffa0f3c79e17ff,
    issue_title: 'test ',
    issue_text: 'tttttttttttttest',
    created_by: 'ahmad',
    created_on: 2020-01-15T13:37:32.119Z,
    updated_on: 2020-01-15T13:37:32.119Z,
    assigned_to: '',
    status_text: '',
    open: true }
```

I want the user to Update as many fields as they want in one shot.

I don't know the number of fields that will be updated in Advance.

I want to send a query like this `updated_issue = { id: '_id', open:false, ...}` So, only the fields in `updated_issue` will be modified.

My code looks like this:

```
...
 updated_issue = { id: '_id', open:false, ..}

...
 var keys = Object.keys(update_issue);

 db.collection(project).updateOne({_id:id}, 
     { for(var k  of keys) { $set: { k: update_issue[k]} } },  /* problem is this line */
     {new:true}, (err,data )=>{ 
                   res.tyep('text').send('success');
                   });
...
```

I want to loop throw an object and assign its values to the corresponding fields in the DB. without Modifying the other fields

Comment: You can't do it inline. Nodejs is not python. Do the for-loop to assign $set properties to a temporary object, then use it in the updateOne.

Comment: can you explain more because I tried this, and failed.

Comment: Ah, one more thing - its behaviour may surprise you if you have nested documents and arrays. Test carefully.

Comment: `cost tmp = {$set:{}};  for(var k  of keys) { tmp.$set[k] = update_issue[k] }; db.collection(project).updateOne({_id:id}, tmp, {new:true}, ()=>{.....})` if you need any logic within for loop, or just `db.collection(project).updateOne({_id:id}, {$set: update_issue}, {new: true}, ()=>{.....})` if update_issue is already good enough.

Comment: In fact you **can** do it inline using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map): `$set: keys.map(k=>{return {k: update_issue[k]}})`, I think it will be closest to your attempt.

Comment: thank you very much .. it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to prepare the object with `$set` then update the doc.

```
...
 updated_issue = { id: '_id', open:false, ..}

...
 var keys = Object.keys(update_issue);
 cost tmp = {$set:{}}; for(var k of keys) { tmp.$set[k] = update_issue[k] }; 

 db.collection(project).updateOne({_id:id} , tmp , {new:true}, (err,data )=>{ 
                   res.tyep('text').send('success');
                   });
...
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can do the update by just using 'update_issue' in place of
 '{ for(var k  of keys) { $set: { k: update_issue[k]} } }',  because it is an object.

```
updated_issue = { id: "_id", open: false, ...};

var keys = Object.keys(update_issue);

db.collection(project).updateOne(
  { _id: id },
  update_issue ,
  { new: true },
  (err, data) => {
    res.tyep("text").send("success");
  }
);
```

Comment: He can, but without $set it will overwrite whole object.